# icons missing after upgrading Xubuntu

Tags: upgrade, updates, xfce, xubuntu

I did the following in my computer:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After restarting the computer, I see the visuals of my Desktop changed. Also, there is not even single folder icon in any drive. Only the name of folder is being displayed and there is no icon. In the panel, certain utilities have lost thier icons too.

[image]

In a window,the folder icons are not available. Also in the left, the thumbnails of Desktop,Filesystem,Documents,Music,etc. are not displayed. In the right(panel), several utilities have the same default icon (such as the terminal emulator,trash,Web browser,Mail Reader,Settings Manager).

The thing is only the icons are not visible, but i can double-click and open the folders. How can I get back those icons(like the default yellow color folder icon) because it is annoying to see only the names of folder displayed without any icon

I did only the upgrade thing I mentioned above, nothing else. (I did not tweak anything.)

When I login as **GUEST** the windows are **normal** as it used to be before

Normal screen before upgrade: 
[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be awesome here.

Comment: Atleast **10 reputation** is required to add images, so could not add a screenshot. The thing is only the icons are not visible, but i can double-click and open the folders. How can I get back those icons(like the default yellow color folder icon) because it is annoying to see only the names of folder displayed without any icon.

Comment: Very true, but you can upload the image to imgur.com and post the link by editing your question. Then, someone with sufficient rep will incorporate the image itself in your question.

Comment: You could also mention if you've "tweaked" Xubuntu in any way: new theme, different file manager, anything else?

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Can you suggest anything i can do??

Comment: That seems a problem with your theme and icons. Can you change them?

Comment: Thank you, @LnxSlck Actually I tried to change the theme in settings manager earlier and did not get anything. Just now changed the icon settings and display is normal as before. But I dont understand why after upgrade, this problem occurred. Will this be happening everytime I upgrade?

Comment: It shouldn't happen after every upgrade. If it does come back and we'll try to figure out what exactly may be breaking your themes.

Comment: I see that now you're compiz. When I installed compiz on xubuntu, my whole set up was ruined. Did you recently install compiz?

Comment: yes I hav installed compiz... will there be problems due to this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue comes from a different selection for the `Settings > Appearance > Icon` theme. From the screenshot it looks to me like you want to select the `elementary Xfce` icon theme.

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since it works with the Guest user and yours not, it would be safe to assume that your personal preferences are corrupted, and that corruption is revealed when *something* changes.

Cleaning your `~/.*` files seem the quickest solution:

```
mkdir config.bk
mv -r ~/.* config.bk/
```

Restart your session, and *voilá*.

If you are curious about the underlying cause you could use `diff` to find out.

```
ls | awk '{print $1 }' > ignore.diff
echo ignore.diff >> ignore.diff
diff -ENwbur -Xignore.diff  ~ ~/config.bk/ > conf.diff
```